# If statement doesn't work even if conditions are met

Tags: python, excel, if-statement

I'm writing some code to automate data entry at work. My issue is that the if statements are not working despite the conditions being met. I've tested the code on two excel files with the exact same data and the statements work with no issues on one file but not the other. There are no errors that appear when run with the file that doesn't work. All other commands have no issues, only the if statements are causing problems.

The only difference I can find with the two files is that one that works is unencrypted and the one that doesn't work is encrypted. I've tested out by unencrypting the file and trying it again, but it still does not work.

Here is a summarized version of what my code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyautogui as pya
import xlwings as xw

# Path for encrypted file

PATH = 'D:\filename.xlsx'

wb = xw.Book(PATH, password=pword)
sheet = wb.sheets['sheetname']
df = sheet.used_range.options(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=True).value
df.head()


if (df['columnname'][row] == healthnum and df['columnname2'][row] == 5):
    pya.hotkey ('5')
elif df['columnname'][row] == healthnum and df['columnname2'][row] == 4.4:
     pya.hotkey ('4')
elif df['columnname'][row] == healthnum and df['columnname2'][row] == 3.4:
     pya.hotkey ('3')
elif df['columnname'][row] == healthnum and df['columnname2'][row] == 2:
     pya.hotkey ('2')
elif df['columnname'][row] == healthnum and df['columnname2'][row] == 1:
     pya.hotkey ('1')
        
pya.hotkey('tab')
```

What's supposed to happen is that if the conditions are met, then the keyboard would input '4' and then tab to the next question. What happens instead is it tabs through all the questions without putting in the data.

EDIT:
I've solved this issue by checking the data types. In one file, the data was imported as a string and in the other file (the one with no issues) the data was imported as integers. So I've converted the columns to integer and everything is going smoothly now. Thanks for everyone's help

Comment: Not enough detail. What is `healthnum`? What floating-points values are in the data frame that could trigger precision errors?

Comment: Sample data for `df` in text form might be helpful.

Comment: @chepner the healthnum is supposed to be an integer but I checked now and it says it is a string. I've altered my macros so that it takes healthnum as a string and I found that it still does not work, it seems that when i do `df['columnname'][row] == healthnum` it is False so that must be where the issue lies

Comment: From my experience: If the code you look at seems to be correct, often the problem is somewhere else. Sounds stupid but maybe that allows to to save some time. I.e. don't further inspect the if-condition. Things to try: Copy and paste the data from one excel file to another and run again. Copy only parts of the data. Add logging.

Comment: Regarding your EDIT, I have found that issue many times. In many places I do an .astype() on the column before I do anything else to make sure it is what I think it should be. I even went as far as creating a dict of {'col_name': type}, ex. {'a_number': int}, so I can just call df.astype(type_dict) and call it a day. If the column doesn't exist, it just ignores it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have any knowledge about Panda, but I think you should remove the whitespaces

```
pya.hotkey ('5')
```

Comment: Hello, the whitespaces are not causing any issues in this situation. I've already tested the code on another file and everything works well, it is just a different file that is having problems